# When setting environment variables in Apache RewriteRule directives, what causes the variable name to be prefixed with "REDIRECT_"?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, environment-variables, naming

I am trying to set Apache environment variables (for use in PHP) with the `[E=VAR:VAL]` flag on RewriteRule rules in an .htaccess file.

I have already discovered the variables are accessed in PHP as server variables `$_SERVER` rather than `$_ENV` (which makes a certain amount of sense). However, my problem is for some rules the `[E=VAR:VAL]` flag works as expected and I end up with a variable `$_SERVER['VAR']` but for other rules I end with a variable `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_VAR']` or `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REDIRECT_VAR']`, etc

A. What causes an environment variable set in Apache using the `[E=VAR:VAL]` flag to get renamed by having "REDIRECT_" prepended to the variable name?

B. What can I do to make sure I end up with an Environment Variable with an unchanged name so I can access it in PHP as `$_SERVER['VAR']` without having to resort to checking for variations of the variable name having one of more instances of "REDIRECT_" prepended to it?

*Partial solution found*. Adding the following to the start of the rewrite rules recreates the original ENV:VAR on each redirect (as well as leaving the REDIRECT_VAR versions there) if they're needed:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_VAR} !^$
RewriteRule .* - [E=VAR:%{ENV:REDIRECT_VAR}]
```

Comment: I always use getenv() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php and haven't yet experienced any weird issues.

Answer (score 84):

This behavior is unfortunate and doesn't even appear to be documented.

## .htaccess per-dir context

Here's what appears to happen in `.htaccess` per-directory (per-dir) context:

Assume that Apache processes an `.htaccess` file that includes rewrite directives.

1. Apache populates its environment variable map with all of the standard CGI / Apache variables
2. Rewriting begins
3. Environment variables are set in `RewriteRule` directives
4. When Apache stops processing the `RewriteRule` directives (because of an `L` flag or the end of the ruleset) and the URL has been changed by a `RewriteRule`, Apache restarts request processing.

   If you're not familiar with this part, see the [`L` flag documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l):

   > thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirect - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.
5. From what I can observe, I believe that when #4 happens, #1 is repeated, then the environment variables that were set in `RewriteRule` directives are prepended with `REDIRECT_` and added to the environment vars map (not necessarily in that order, but the end result consisting of that combination).

   This step is where the chosen variable names are wiped out, and in a moment I will explain why that is so important and inconvenient.

## Restoring variable names

When I originally ran into this issue, I was doing something like the following in `.htaccess` (simplified):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.projects\.

RewriteRule (.*) subdomains/%1/docroot/$1

RewriteRule (.+/docroot)/ - [L,E=EFFECTIVE_DOCUMENT_ROOT:$1]
```

If I were to set the environment variable in the first `RewriteRule`, Apache would restart the rewriting process and prepend the variable with `REDIRECT_` (steps #4 & 5 above), thus I'd lose access to it via the name I assigned.

In this case, the first `RewriteRule` changes the URL, so after both `RewriteRule`s are processed, Apache restarts the procedure and processes the `.htaccess` again.  The second time, the first `RewriteRule` is skipped because of the `RewriteCond` directive, but the second `RewriteRule` matches, sets the environment variable (again), and, importantly, *doesn't change the URL*.  So the request / rewriting process does not start over, and the variable name I chose sticks.  In this case I actually have both `REDIRECT_EFFECTIVE_DOCUMENT_ROOT` and `EFFECTIVE_DOCUMENT_ROOT`.  If I were to use an `L` flag on the first `RewriteRule`, I'd only have `EFFECTIVE_DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

@trowel's partial solution works similarly: the rewrite directives are processed again, the renamed variable is assigned to the original name again, and if the URL does not change, the process is over and the assigned variable name sticks.

## Why those techniques are inadequate

Both of those techniques suffer from a major flaw: when the rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file where you set environment variables rewrite the URL to a more deeply nested directory that has an `.htaccess` file that does any rewriting, your assigned variable name is wiped out again.

Say you have a directory layout like this:

```
docroot/
        .htaccess
        A.php
        B.php
        sub/
                .htaccess
                A.php
                B.php
```

And a `docroot/.htaccess` like this:

```
RewriteRule ^A\.php sub/B.php [L]

RewriteRule .* - [E=MAJOR:flaw]
```

So you request `/A.php`, and it's rewritten to `sub/B.php`.  You still have your `MAJOR` variable.

However, if you have any rewrite directives in `docroot/sub/.htaccess` (even just `RewriteEngine Off` or `RewriteEngine On`), your `MAJOR` variable disappears.  That's because once the URL is rewritten to `sub/B.php`, `docroot/sub/.htaccess` is processed, and if it contains any rewrite directives, rewrite directives in `docroot/.htaccess` are not processed again.  If you had a `REDIRECT_MAJOR` after `docroot/.htaccess` was processed (e.g. if you omit the `L` flag from the first `RewriteRule`), you'll still have it, but those directives won't run again to set your chosen variable name.

## Inheritance

So, say you want to:

1. set environment variables in `RewriteRule` directives at a particular level of the directory tree (like `docroot/.htaccess`)
2. have them available in scripts at deeper levels
3. have them available with the assigned names
4. be able to have rewrite directives in more deeply nested `.htaccess` files

A possible solution is to use `RewriteOptions inherit` directives in the more deeply nested `.htaccess` files.  That allows you to re-run the rewrite directives in less deeply nested files and use the techniques outlined above to set the variables with the chosen names.  However, note that this increases complexity because you have to be more careful crafting the rewrite directives in the less deeply nested files so that they don't cause problems when run again from the more deeply nested directories.  I believe Apache strips the per-dir prefix for the more deeply nested directory and runs the rewrite directives in the less deeply nested files on that value.

## @trowel's technique

As far as I can see, support for using a construct like `%{ENV:REDIRECT_VAR}` in the value component of a `RewriteRule` `E` flag (e.g. `[E=VAR:%{ENV:REDIRECT_VAR}]`) does not appear to be [documented](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e):

> VAL may contain backreferences ($N or %N) which will be expanded.

It does appear to work, but if you want to avoid relying on something undocumented (please correct me if I'm wrong about that), it can easily be done this way instead:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_VAR} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=VAR:%1]
```

## SetEnvIf

I don't recommend relying on this, because it doesn't seem to be consistent with the [documented behavior](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif) (see below), but this (in `docroot/.htaccess`, with Apache 2.2.20) works for me:

```
SetEnvIf REDIRECT_VAR (.+) VAR=$1
```

> Only those environment variables defined by earlier SetEnvIf[NoCase] directives are available for testing in this manner.

## Why?

I don't know what the rationale for prefixing these names with `REDIRECT_` is -- not surprising, since it doesn't appear to be mentioned in the Apache documentation sections for [mod_rewrite directives](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html), [`RewriteRule` flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_e), or [environment variables](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html).

At the moment it seems like a big nuisance to me, in the absence of an explanation for why it's better than leaving the assigned names alone.  The lack of documentation only contributes to my skepticism about it.

Being able to assign environment variables in rewrite rules is useful, or at least, it would be.  But the usefulness is greatly diminished by this name-changing behavior.  The complexity of this post illustrates how nuts this behavior and the hoops that have to be jumped through to try to overcome it are.

Comment: Came across another rule that falls under the category of annoying undocumented weirdness. On some servers, environment variable names must be prefixed with HTTP_. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073144/environment-variables-are-not-passed-from-htaccess-to-php)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand one thing. In your example if the rules are: 
`RewriteRule ^A\.php sub/B.php [L]` and then
`RewriteRule .* - [E=MAJOR:flaw]`, if the first rule matches, `MAJOR` won't be set cause the first rule matches and is the last (L flag). The URL is rewritten and apache re-iterates over the `mod_rewrite`'s inner loop and this time matches `RewriteRule .* - [E=MAJOR:flaw]`, sets the environment variable and only then goes after the next `.htaccess` inside `/sub`. Is it correct?

Comment: @tonix Just going from what I wrote here, no, that doesn't sound correct. The way I described it, the first `RewriteRule` rewrites the URL to `sub/B.php` and then it's game over for `docroot/.htaccess`: the env variable never actually gets set. (Describing that as the env variable "disappearing" may not be the best way to put it.) Again, that's if there's a `sub/.htaccess` that contains any rewriting related directive.

Comment: Taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484739/mod-rewrite-unexpected-behavior-l-flag/12106419#12106419`: **If the URI changed L will re-inject into the the next round (the outer loop)** So I guess that if a URL is rewritten with [L] flag set, mod_rewrite will pass to the next round, but this time taking into consideration the most inner `.htaccess` file inside of the rewritten path (in this case `sub/.htaccess`). At least, this is what I understand from your answer and the answer I linked.

Comment: FWIW, here are some Apache docs that explicitly talk about the "REDIRECT_" prefix: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/custom-error.html. I sympathize with how annoying it is, though — just got bitten by it, myself.

Comment: Apache HTTPD Subversion history indicates this code in `modules/http/http_request.c` that runs `rename_original_env()` was added in the bulk import from 1.3.x CVS, and I can't seem to find that earlier history anywhere now. You should file a bug report to have them explain and document this more clearly.

Comment: I am running with Apache 2.4 + mod_fastcgi + php-fpm with 'alias' directive to mapping to the external fastcgi path, I think this is the cause of my 'REDIRECT_' env var renaming, after switching to using 'mod_proxy_fastcgi', even with same .htaccess rule, the problem no longer exists.

Comment: There's a bug available about this behaviour as well: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58739

Answer (score 9):

I haven't tested this at all and I know it doesn't address points A or B, but there is some description of this issue in the comments in PHP documentation and some possible solutions for accessing these variables using `$_SERVER['VAR']`:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.php#79811

**EDIT** - some more responses to the question offered:

**A:** The environment variables are renamed by Apache if they are involved in a redirect.  For example, if you have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php - [E=VAR1:'hello',E=VAR2:'world']
```

Then you may access VAR1 and VAR2 using `$_SERVER['VAR1']` and `$_SERVER['VAR2']`.  However, if you redirect the page like so:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php index2.php [E=VAR1:'hello',E=VAR2:'world']
```

Then you must use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_VAR1']`, etc.

**B:** The best way to overcome this issue is to process the variables that you're interested in using PHP.  Create a function that runs through the `$_SERVER` array and finds the items that you need.  You might even use a function like this:

```
function myGetEnv($key) {
    $prefix = "REDIRECT_";
    if(array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER))
        return $_SERVER[$key];
    foreach($_SERVER as $k=>$v) {
        if(substr($k, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
            if(substr($k, -(strlen($key))) == $key)
                return $v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the comments. They confirm the issue and do provide a workaround but it just shifts the problem from PHP to extra code in the .htaccess
I'm hoping an Apache guru might know how to make the name persist so no workaround code is needed! (I would give you +1 but don't have enough rep to do it)

Comment: @trowel - see changes to my answer

Comment: Thanks thetaiko, it transpires the renaming is a feature introduced in Apache 2.0, which is intended to help track variables through redirects.

Nice PHP function but I'd probably go with a preg_match starting with /^($REDIRECT_)* to catch any number of redirects in one hit.

At the apache end of things I've found a solution (added to question)

Answer (score 1):

As I don't want to change any of my code *(nor can I change code of the libraries used)*, I went with the following approach: whilst bootstrapping my application – e.g. in my `index.php` – I rework the `$_ENV` superglobal so that variables prefixed with `REDIRECT_` are rewritten to their normal intended name:

```
// Fix ENV vars getting prepended with `REDIRECT_` by Apache
foreach ($_ENV as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 9) === 'REDIRECT_') {
        $_ENV[str_replace('REDIRECT_', '', $key)] = $value;
        putenv(str_replace('REDIRECT_', '', $key) . '=' . $value);
    }
}
```

Not only do we directly set it in `$_ENV`, but we also store it using `putenv()`. This way existing code and libraries – which might use `getenv()` – can work fine.

---

On a sidenote: if you're extracting headers – like `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` – in your code, you need to do the same kind of manipulation on `$_SERVER`:

```
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (substr($key, 0, 9) === 'REDIRECT_') {
        $_SERVER[str_replace('REDIRECT_', '', $key)] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `str_replace('REDIRECT_', '', $key)` must be `preg_replace('/^(REDIRECT\_)*/', '', $key)` to replace only beginning of indexes