# Using variable in RewriteCond condition patern

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I want to associate user Ids to a specific application Id like:

```
<user_id> <app_id>  
615 1
616 7
617 3
618 3
```

My URIs looks like:

```
/<app_id>/<user_id>/...
```

Now, I want to be able to easily change the application without impacting the user bookmarks. In my example, I want both

```
/1/615/index.html or /3/615/index.html
```

to be served as

```
/1/615/index.html
```

With the following rule, I get infinite loop:

```
RewriteMap map dbm:user-application.map
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /${map:$2}/$2/$3 [R,L]              
...
#other proxy code to forward request to applications
```

I understand that after the redirection, Apache will always execute the same rule.
I then tried to add a rewrite condition to block the loop, like

```
RewriteMap map dbm:user-application.map
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/${map:$2}
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ /${map:$2}/$2/$3 [R,L]
```

If I read correctly my rewrite logs, I can see that the variable !^/${map:$2} is not replaced in the condition pattern, but checked "as it". And then the condition is always true, and I still get my infinite loop.

Any idea to block the loop as soon as the application id match my map?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798099/how-to-block-multiple-mod-rewrite-passes-or-infinite-loops-in-a-htaccess-cont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/3/615/index.html is correctly redirecting to /1/615/index.html

The problem is that you are redirecting /1/615/index.html to /1/615/index.html as well - you want to detect the case in which the map transform is a no-op and *not* redirect at all in that case.

If you don't care about the user-facing URL, just change the [R,L] to [L] (removing the R) and you should be fine since it won't trigger a new round-trip from the client.

You're right that the $2 backreference won't work in a RewriteCond expression; this is because the RewriteRule hasn't yet been evaluated.  You might be able to use %n - style backreferences to a regex in a previous RewriteCond...

```
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9]+)/
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URI} !^/${map:%1}
```

But I have not tested this, so YMMV.

Comment: Well, I cannot provide the exact fix I used anymore, but the answer you provide is indeed the way I explored. Thanks!

Comment: This blog post addresses an extremely similar case: http://www.jeremytunnell.com/posts/mod_rewrite-attempting-to-bend-rewritemap-rewritecond-and-rewriterule-to-my-will