# mod rewrite does not stop processing last rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to achieve this with mod rewrite:

If a user visits `mysite.com/app/[somepage].php`, they will see `mysite.php/[somepage].php`
If a user visits `mysite.com/[somepage].php`, they will be rewritten to `mysite.com/test.php`

The value in square brackets are arbitrary.

This is what I have now:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.+) $1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.+) test.php [NC,L]
```

However, both `mysite.com/app/index.php` and `mysite.com/index.php` will rewrite to `mysite.com/test.php`. It is as if the last rule is always processed. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Either use `[END]` with Apache 2.4 or mask the second rule with a `RewriteCond` for the `REDIRECT_STATUS`.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? I thought the L flag means the rewrite would stop processsing?

Comment: See [Mod\_Rewrite unexpected behavior L flag](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12106419) and [How to block multiple mod\_rewrite passes (or infinite loops) in a .htaccess context](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7798099)

Comment: RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
worked. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Or match `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead.