# Environment variables are not passed from .htaccess to PHP

Tags: php, apache, cgi, environment-variables

I am trying to pass an environment variable from .htaccess through to PHP.  This works just fine on my local WAMP server, but on the server where my website is hosted, it fails without reason.

Here's my test configuration:

.htaccess:

```
SetEnv TEST_VARIABLE test_value
```

test.php:

```
<pre>
getenv('TEST_VARIABLE') = <?php print getenv('TEST_VARIABLE'); ?>

getenv('REDIRECT_TEST_VARIABLE') = <?php print getenv('REDIRECT_TEST_VARIABLE'); ?>
</pre>
```

On my local server, getting test.php correctly returns:

```
getenv('TEST_VARIABLE') = test_value
getenv('REDIRECT_TEST_VARIABLE') =
```

But on the production server, it returns:

```
getenv('TEST_VARIABLE') = 
getenv('REDIRECT_TEST_VARIABLE') =
```

Things I've ruled out:

1. `mod_env` is not installed/enabled by the host.  Can't be, because then `SetEnv` would not be recognized and I'd get a 500 while processing the .htaccess.
2. `AllowOverrides` in `httpd.conf` for this directory doesn't include `FileInfo`.  Can't be, because then Apache would throw an error "SetEnv not allowed here" when encountering the `SetEnv` directive and I'd get a 500 again.
3. `variables_order` in php.ini doesn't include 'E'.  This would explain the `$_ENV` superglobal being empty (which it is), but not why `getenv()` doesn't return values for these variables.
4. Entire environment is screwed up.  Can't be, because `getenv('PATH')` and `getenv('SERVER_NAME')` still return valid values.

At this point I'm at a loss as to what configuration could be causing this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think using setenv normally works in .htaccess. It's a shell script command (bash, C shell, etc.). If your server *does* support setenv, according to https://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/36/Using+Environment+Variables+in+PHP#gs you need to have the variable name start with HTTP_.

Comment: SetEnv _is_ an .htaccess command, but you nailed it: once I prefixed the variable with HTTP_, everything worked.  I haven't seen that requirement documented in any "official" source, which is strange, but hey, if it works don't touch it, right?

Comment: The same requirement seems to go for RewriteRule .* - (E=HTTP_VAR:VAL) on some servers.

Comment: just ran into this same problem, so strange that it is not documented anywhere. In my case, this didn't happen with a PHP script, but rather in Perl.

Comment: Anybody ever found this documented anywhere? So strange!

Comment: Seems that suexec will clean the environment before calling PHP, thus throwing away your SetEnv variables. The HTTP_ trick will work on servers where suexec has been compiled to allow it.

Answer (score 5):

If you are running your home server on a Mac or have suEXEC enabled, there are security measures in place to strip any non-http environment variables that are defined, therefore they won't appear in $_ENV['APPLICATION_ENV']. You CAN, however access these through a native PHP function to get the same thing.

```
$var = apache_getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');
```

That function will get any environment variable defined with SetEnv in your .htaccess file, or any environment variable that is set in php.ini, even if PHP removes these from the $_ENV variable.

You could then define the environment variable within PHP if you want, although not recommended.

```
$_ENV['APPLICATION_ENV'] = apache_getenv('APPLICATION_ENV');
```

Or the better solution: just define a global:

```
define('APPLICATION_ENV', apache_getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'));
```

Once you do that, it should work as desired.