# Setting server variables inside the .htaccess file is prefixing variable names with REQUEST_

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mamp

I am trying to set some environment variables inside my .htaccess file like so:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

SetEnv DB_NAME my_database
SetEnv DB_USER root
SetEnv DB_PASSWORD root
SetEnv DB_HOST 127.0.0.1

# END WordPress
```

However when I use any of those variables inside my php code they are prefixed with `REQUEST_` for some odd reason, and this is only on my computer.

So for example `$_SERVER['DB_NAME']` won't work but `$_SERVER['REQUEST_DB_NAME']` will work fine.

Like I said this is only on my computer which is using MAMP PRO for running apache.

Any reason why this would be happening, it makes no sense to me as I didn't see any configs that would be causing this too

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but I had to fix the issue with a snippet to strip out `REDIRECT_` if it existed. So now instead of doing `$_SERVER['DB_USER'];` I have to use `getVar('DB_USER');`

```
function getVar($key) {
   $prefix = "REDIRECT_";
   if(array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER))
   return $_SERVER[$key];
   foreach($_SERVER as $k=>$v) {
     if(substr($k, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
     if(substr($k, -(strlen($key))) == $key)
     return $v;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

If anyone found a solution to this without adding extra PHP code please let me know!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21137640/htaccess-setenv-redirect-prefix