# Apache set environment variable

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

I'm trying to set environment variable(Apache/2.2.22) in my virtual host(not via .htaccess):

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/path/to/something.php* EXTENSION=php
```

However, in php I see only `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_REDIRECT_EXTENSION'], which is equal  'php'`
Why there is prefix `REDIRECT_REDIRECT_`? I expected to get it via `$_SERVER['EXTENSION']`.

However, when I set

```
 SetEnvIf Host test\.local RUN_CODE=test
```

It works properly, and I can get it via `$_SERVER['RUN_CODE']`.

Any advices?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050444/when-setting-environment-variables-in-apache-rewriterule-directives-what-causes

Comment: Make sure your PHP file handling the request is not the "prepend" file, else it may be triggered before that htaccess directive but outputs after.

Comment: @CharlSteynberg Look my last update of the comment. Thanks