# How do I install a React app based on react-router's browserHistory into a WordPress page on Apache?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, reactjs, react-router

I've built a React app to run on a single page of a WordPress site (http://example.com/myapp/). I'm using react-router. It works great with `hashHistory`, but I want to use the clean URLs that `browserHistory` offers.

I'm writing mod_rewrite and SetEnvIf recipes to solve the problem, but there is a strange complication with the WordPress rewrite rule. When I set `REQUEST_URI`, PHP winds up seeing that setting in `REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI`, which of course isn't where WordPress looks.

How can I set up the Apache side of a react-router app on a WordPress page?

Background: [When setting environment variables in Apache RewriteRule directives, what causes the variable name to be prefixed with "REDIRECT_"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050444/when-setting-environment-variables-in-apache-rewriterule-directives-what-causes#10128290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried lots of things to make this work without touching WordPress, but finally I gave up and entered a well-commented patch into my WordPress `/index.php`.

`.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN myapp 
#  
# Set the REQUEST_URI to just /myapp for any deeper URI for the myapp React router. 
# 
# Unfortunately, this winds up setting REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI rather than 
# REQUEST_URI. See /index.php for a custom patch that works around this. 
# 
# Issue documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10128290/1426950 
SetEnvIf Request_URI "myapp/.*" REQUEST_URI=/myapp/ 
# END myapp
```

`/index.php`:

```
/**
 *
 * CUSTOM PATCH
 *
 * Work around an Apache issue documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10128290/1426950
 * We need it for the React app at /myapp/.
 *
 * We need the WordPress page at /myapp/ to be served for any URL beginning
 * with /myapp/, so that we can control that namespace with React. To
 * accomplish this, we set REQUEST_URI in the .htaccess, but a subsequent rewrite
 * pushes that setting over to REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI and resets REQUEST_URI.
 *
 * This PHP code fools WordPress into thinking Apache did what we wanted.
 *
 */
if (
  $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI'] !== null
) {
  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_REQUEST_URI'];
}
```

Now everything works perfectly and WordPress serves the page at `/myapp/` for all URLs of the React app (`/myapp/foo`, `myapp/bar/123`, etc.).