# Apache mod_rewrite [E] Redirect prefix with RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

In an Apache server, I need to disable keepalive if a specific URL is matched.
To do so, I used mod_rewrite to set it then let the script run its course.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/specific_url
RewriteRule  ^ - [E=nokeepalive]
.......
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Now my problem is that `nokeepalive` end up being prefixed/renamed to with REDIRECT_ if it matches
From this question : [When setting environment variables in Apache RewriteRule directives, what causes the variable name to be prefixed with "REDIRECT_"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050444/when-setting-environment-variables-in-apache-rewriterule-directives-what-causes)
I assumed it was due to the `RewriteRule`
But it is not prefixed **if I remove the RewriteCond** (which would disable `keepAlive` globaly with any URL)

Is there a way to prevent this prefixing with RewriteCond ?
I cannot use `SetEnvIf` since I use `mod_rewrite` so I must use `RewriteRule`.

SetEnv/SetEnviF also won't work as they can not read  from variable that were not assigned using SetEnv/SetEnvif.
I tried with SetEnvIf to define only if REDIRECT_nokeepalive exist ( since nokeepalive just have to be defined, regardless of the value ) - but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot use SetEnvIf since I use mod_rewrite so I must use RewriteRule.

You could use mod_setenvif with `<If>`.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /regextomatchurl/">
# or use <If "%{REQUEST_URI} == 'urlstring'">
SetEnv nokeepalive 1
</If>
```

You can remove that rewrite rule.

### OR:

You can just add this, it might work, not tested:

```
SetEnv nokeepalive ${REDIRECT_nokeepalive}
```

### Edit:

Remember to add `PassEnv REDIRECT_nokeepalive` before `SetEnv` because `SetEnv` cannot read env variables from mod_rewrite.

### Just to point out:

You have two spaces here, it could cause future problems in other RewriteRule(s):

```
RewriteRule  ^ - [E=nokeepalive]
           ^^
```

Comment: I used the second approach after setting it a first time.
It's ugly but it works and I found no other workaround right now with that behaviour of Apache.

Comment: The 
SetEnv nokeepalive ${REDIRECT_nokeepalive}  
won't work as SetEnv can not read  from variable that were not assigned using SetEnv or SetEnvif.
I tried with SetEnvIf to define only if REDIRECT_nokeepalive exist ( since nokeepalive just have to be defined, regardless of the value ) - but to no avail.

Comment: @R.Damasinoro you can use `PassEnv REDIRECT_nokeepalive` before SetEnv

Comment: @R.Damasinoro, also you might need to change `${REDIRECT_nokeepalive}` to `%{REDIRECT_nokeepalive}e`