# Setting an env variable based on host and request uri in apache2

Tags: php, apache2

We have a php-based website and want to set an env variable based on host and the first part of the request uri. The site is running apache with `mod_rewrite` and fpm.

I found [`SetEnvIfExpr`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifexpr) and tried to add this to the `.htaccess`:

```
SetEnvIfExpr "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ m#.*example.com.*# && %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/de.*#" RUN_CODE=german
```

I want to match all urls starting with `example.com/de`.

Doing a `var_dump($_SERVER['RUN_CODE']);` in my `index.php` gives me `NULL`.

Through trial and error I figured out the following:

- When I modify the last request (the one matching `REQUEST_URI`) to `^.*de.*` it works correctly. Sadly, that's not really a solution because this could match other urls not starting with `/de`.
- I suspected this issue comes from the processing order of `mod_setenvif` and `mod_rewrite`. `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);` gives me only `/de/...` but I found that modifying the regex to `^/in.*de.*` matches. `^/index.php/de.*` does not.

Comment: does `^/index\.php/de.*` match?

Comment: @Alex No, it does not.

Answer (score 2):

If rewriting the URL causes an internal redirect, Apache renames your env variable from `RUN_CODE` to `REDIRECT_RUN_CODE`.

This is common behavior of the Apache2 webserver, compare:

- [When setting environment variables in Apache RewriteRule directives, what causes the variable name to be prefixed with "REDIRECT_"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3050444/367456)

So as it looks like you're building on top of the effect of an internal redirect, from PHP's end the variable name is different:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['REDIRECT_RUN_CODE']); # instead of 'RUN_CODE'
```

Comment: Looks like that's it. Now I just need to figure out how to tell the application to use `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_RUN_CODE']` (that part is handled by a framework)

Comment: Would be better to avoid the redirect :-D of course you could patch the app's index.php to $_SERVER['RUN_CODE'] = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_RUN_CODE']
or put a later SetEnv in .htaccess ?

Comment: I am wondering which redirect causes the variable renaming ... The linked post talks about setting env variables in `RewriteRule`s, but you are using `SetEnvIfExpr` ...